# how to add label/text to each coloumn in Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using ColumnChart to draw a chart and I need to have text on each coloumn (at the top of it)

I can't find any documentation about this, I was wondering if someone can help please?

Something similar to this:

[image: Chart]
<sub>(source: [seo-website-designer.com](http://seo-website-designer.com/Media/Backlink-Pages-Subset.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible with the new Google Charts, the nearest you can get is to have a tooltip but those can only be triggered on hover at the moment.